# How to deal with modals not opening in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, forms, modal-dialog, phantomjs, watir

I have a **Watir** code that uses **Phantomjs** as headless browser. I'm trying to fill a form on  website using this code (because Phantomjs doesn't show modal on simple click (`browser.link(id: 'choise-sity').click)`):

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
browser.goto 'http://sales.ubrr.ru/open'

browser.execute_script(" $('#modalCityChoise').show();$('#modalCityChoise').css({'opacity':'1', 'top':'0'})")
browser.link(text: 'Архангельск').click

browser.screenshot.save 'a.png'
```

Current code does show modal, but I'm unable to click links there after.
My question is: is there an easier way to deal with modals in PhantomJS - they said they added support to modals? Or how to deal with this particular example by javascript injection?

**edit:** I managed to deal with this modal just by changing a value of hidden input `browser.execute_script(" $('#OpenBkiForm_city_code').val('4600000100000') ")` - but question still lingers.

Comment: The click should work. You probably have to wait until the modal is visible/invisible. Btw, those are modals not popups. See [this](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/34d41e7661c9b1003cb2) for an example with CasperJS. Don't forget to set the viewport size to something desktop like.

Comment: @ArtjomB., oh! you were right, it opens fine if I wait for some time:-) I didn't think that it needs some time after clicking unlike links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misinterpreted the issue - modals were managed correctly by Phantomjs, but I couldn't prove it because at the time of my screenshoting they were only beginning to fade in, which I haven't thought of.
The real issue was that I couldn't press the button in modal window. Turns out that was because of the window size - even when screenshots captured the button, it wasn't really accessible to Watir somehow. This resolved the whole issue:

```
$browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
```

Answer (score 1):

Modals can be implemented differently. Sometimes they are animated which makes it necessary to wait until they are fully visible to then work on them further.

In your case you can use [Wait:until](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Wait):

```
browser.goto 'http://sales.ubrr.ru/open'
Watir::Wait.until { browser.a(:id => "modalCityChoise").visible? }
browser.link(text: 'Архангельск').click
browser.screenshot.save 'a.png'
```

Comment: thank you, transitions tricked me into thinking that problem was in modals themselves:-)